# Setting up RestKit in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, restkit

My name is Marco and I am trying to use RestKit in my project. Im brand new to RestKit and iOS in general, but very experienced .NET Programmer.

Could you folks help me?

The problem is I can't setup XCode to use RestKit. It ALWAYS says when I try to compile it:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

_CGRectIsEmpty", referenced from:

```
  -[RKAbstractTableController addToOverlayView:modally:] in libRestKit.a(RKAbstractTableController.o)
```

"_CGRectContainsPoint", referenced from:

```
  -[RKAbstractTableController resizeTableViewForKeyboard:] in libRestKit.a(RKAbstractTableController.o)
```

"_CGRectZero", referenced from:

```
  -[RKAbstractTableController initWithTableView:viewController:] in libRestKit.a(RKAbstractTableController.o)

  -[RKAbstractTableController showImageInOverlay:] in libRestKit.a(RKAbstractTableController.o)

  -[RKRefreshGestureRecognizer initWithTarget:action:] in libRestKit.a(RKRefreshGestureRecognizer.o)

  -[RKRefreshTriggerView initWithFrame:] in libRestKit.a(RKRefreshTriggerView.o)

  -[RKAbstractTableController initWithTableView:viewController:] in libRestKit.a(RKAbstractTableController.o)

  -[RKAbstractTableController showImageInOverlay:] in libRestKit.a(RKAbstractTableController.o)

  -[RKRefreshGestureRecognizer initWithTarget:action:] in libRestKit.a(RKRefreshGestureRecognizer.o)

  -[RKRefreshTriggerView initWithFrame:] in libRestKit.a(RKRefreshTriggerView.o)

  -[RKAbstractTableController initWithTableView:viewController:] in libRestKit.a(RKAbstractTableController.o)

  -[RKAbstractTableController showImageInOverlay:] in libRestKit.a(RKAbstractTableController.o)

  -[RKRefreshGestureRecognizer initWithTarget:action:] in libRestKit.a(RKRefreshGestureRecognizer.o)

  -[RKRefreshTriggerView initWithFrame:] in libRestKit.a(RKRefreshTriggerView.o)
```

"_CGRectGetWidth", referenced from:

```
  -[RKRefreshGestureRecognizer observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] in libRestKit.a(RKRefreshGestureRecognizer.o)

  -[RKRefreshTriggerView layoutSubviews] in libRestKit.a(RKRefreshTriggerView.o)
```

"_CGRectGetMidY", referenced from:

```
  -[RKRefreshTriggerView layoutSubviews] in libRestKit.a(RKRefreshTriggerView.o)
```

"_CGRectIntegral", referenced from:

```
  -[RKRefreshTriggerView layoutSubviews] in libRestKit.a(RKRefreshTriggerView.o)
```

"_CGRectGetHeight", referenced from:

```
  -[RKRefreshTriggerView layoutSubviews] in libRestKit.a(RKRefreshTriggerView.o)
```

"_CGRectOffset", referenced from:

```
  -[RKRefreshTriggerView layoutSubviews] in libRestKit.a(RKRefreshTriggerView.o)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

When I remove the -ObjC -all_load linker flags, my project builds "fine". But then I tried to use it and I got the error:

2012-06-29 10:40:08.346 AgroERP[5234:fb03] -[NSURL queryParameters]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e4cd60

2012-06-29 10:40:08.349 AgroERP[5234:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL queryParameters]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e4cd60'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x1780022 0x19e6cd6 0x1781cbd 0x16e6ed0 0x16e6cb2 0x2424c 0x2405f 0x241cf 0x240d4 0x2751 0x1781e99 0xa0114e 0xa010e6 0xaa7ade 0xaa7fa7 0xaa6d8a 0xa262cf 0xa265e6 0xa0cdc4 0xa00634 0x1f8bef5 0x1754195 0x16b8ff2 0x16b78da 0x16b6d84 0x16b6c9b 0x1f8a7d8 0x1f8a88a 0x9fe626 0x1fac 0x1f45 0x1)

terminate called throwing an exception

in the line:
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"http://192.168.1.101/AgroERPAPI/AuthenticationClient.svc"];

Please, I apologize for bothering you but I really need help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Those are part of the Core Graphics framework so it looks like its not being included for some reason. Make sure it is added into the project and that it has the proper build targets selected. Look at the frameworks in your build settings.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue for me. CoreGraphics was added to my app target, but it was not included in the test target and that caused a compile error.